# Apply function on list of multiple lists of two dataframes by rows

Tags: r, apply

Pardon me if this questions has been answered before but I searched and couldn't find one.
I have a list containing multiple lists containing two dataframes. I want to apply t.test between first row of dataframe 1 and first row of dataframe 2 and so on.

I tried this:

```
list1 <- list(set1 = data.frame(rnorm(100), rexp(100)), set2 = data.frame(rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3), rexp(100, rate = 4))) 

list2 <- list(set1 = data.frame(rnorm(100), rexp(100)), set2 = data.frame(rnorm(100, mean = 6, sd = 4), rexp(100, rate = 2)))

mylist <- list(list1, list2)

ttest<-function(list){
        df1 <- list$set1
        df2 <- list$set2
        testresults<-rep(NA,nrow(df1))
        for (j in seq(nrow(df1))){ 

               testresults[j] <- t.test(df1[j,], df2[j,])$p.value                
        }
        return(as.matrix(testresults))}
lapply(mylist,ttest)
```

This works fine but takes a lot of time because of this for loop and since the actual data is much larger. I want to replace the for loop with an apply function(if possible). Please suggest.

Comment: The bottleneck is the actual `t.test` function, which you can verify by [profiling your code](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html). Your memory-allocation + for loop approach is actually correct here, and the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to use `lapply` with a function taking more than one arguments, which is `Map`. So you can replace `ttest` in your code with

```
ttest2 <- function(list) {
    df1 <- list$set1
    df2 <- list$set2
    l1 <- unlist(apply(df1, 1, list), recursive = FALSE)
    l2 <- unlist(apply(df2, 1, list), recursive = FALSE)
    testresults <- unlist(Map(function(x,y) t.test(x,y)$p.value, x=l1, y=l2))
    return(as.matrix(testresults))
}
```

This seems to be faster. I extended your data frames to have 10000 rows (it runs quite fast with 100 and can't see the difference much) and got

```
system.time(lapply(mylist,ttest))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 12.736   0.000  12.760 
system.time(lapply(mylist,ttest2))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  3.825   0.000   3.833
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
res1 <- sapply(mylist, function(x) {
                   x1 <- do.call(`cbind`,x)
                   apply(x1, 1, function(y) t.test(y[1:2], y[3:4])$p.value)
                })
```

Using your function

```
 res2 <- sapply(mylist, ttest)
 identical(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```